# How to get the keyboard to not be auto capitalised

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview

I have a UITextview for email and a UITextview for password.
I have the password view set to passwordTextView.isSecureTextEntry = true, with this the keyboard loads with lower case letters.
How do I set the keyboard to load with lower case letters for the email view without being secure text entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean UITextField instead of UITextView?

```
yourTextField.autocapitalizationType = .none
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. I have so many textViews in this app but you’re right, I did actually use textFields for these windows. Cheers